# gogo: CommandNotFoundException: Command not found: services

Tags: osgi, apache-zookeeper, apache-felix, dosgi

I know some of the commands have changed names when Apache Felix started using GoGo

For example: `ps --> lb` (list bundles)

What is the equivalent for `services <BUNDLENO>`

I am trying to get the following output from my console:

```
services 5

Distributed OSGi Zookeeper-Based Discovery Single-Bundle Distribution (6) provides:
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
... other services ...
----
objectClass = org.osgi.service.cm.ManagedService
felix.fileinstall.filename = org.apache.cxf.dosgi.discovery.zookeeper.cfg
service.id = 38
service.pid = org.apache.cxf.dosgi.discovery.zookeeper
zookeeper.host = localhost
zookeeper.port = 2181
zookeeper.timeout = 3000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> inspect capability service 5

check more details here

> help inspect

Comment: Note that you can abbreviate "capability" to "cap" or even just "c".